# Which process wrote to which memory address?

Tags: linux, memory, c++, profiling

Recently, I've been seeing a wide variety of memory-related crashes at work (C++ applications on Ubuntu 14.04). Our applications use a properietary third party library to interface with real time data and are heavily multi-threaded. The errors spat out by glibc have been "double free or corruption" and "detected corrupted double-linked list" under various circumstances. The cores recovered from these show crashes occurring both in the third party code (more frequently) and in our own code (less frequently). The unifying characteristic is that every crash corresponds with a `new`/`malloc` or a `delete`/`free`.

Unfortunately, there is very little room for a debugger in this environment. The applications are highly speed sensitive and the input data and operating circumstances can only be approximated when seeking to reproduce a crash because everything in the environment is real time.

That being said, my question is this: what utilities exist that might illuminate exactly which parts of what process are touching memory they shouldn't be? Since crashes can't be reproduced reliably, my only option procedurally is to capture data and then examine it after a crash has occurred. To that end, I found [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/) and [Sysprof](http://sysprof.com/), but I'm not sure if either are appropriate tools for the task.

I apologize for the vagueness of the question and am grateful in advance for any guidance on this issue.

Comment: *"Since crashes can't be reproduced reliably"* -> Why not?  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6152232/1151724).   Of course, if you don't have the source for the proprietary parts, having a core dump might not be very helpful, but it at least would be for your own code.   It may also be possible to locate the error by doing test runs inside `valgrind` for a while.

Comment: Yeah, there are fairly reliable cores and we do have the source for the third party library. So, that works out. The reason the crashes can't be reproduced is because the input data for our applications is generated in real time and entirely externally. We don't store it, so we can't reproduce any given execution exactly.

Comment: Also: *"what process are touching memory they shouldn't be?"* -> **It's whichever process crashed.**   It is not some other process stepping on them.  The OS will not allow that, which is exactly why you get slapped for things like double free or corruption.  The error is in the crashed process, not anywhere else.

Comment: Indeed. I suppose it's more of a question of whether it's third party code or our code. But since very similarly presenting errors occur in both, I've gone looking for tools to shed light. You mentioned `valgrind` for this; I'll do my due Googling, but do you have a favored reference for this type of query?

Comment: Valgrind has a home page and copious documentation.  It will catch memory access violations and provide a backtrace.   You can also get a back trace [from a core dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis), although again this is most useful if you have the source and can provide a binary with debugging symbols in.   Without that it is much sketchier to pin anything down -- but I think that is a logical restriction which will apply no matter what; the information you need simply doesn't exist in a useful form.

Comment: In case there is any confusion (*"there are fairly reliable cores"*), the "core" in "core dump" is not a really a reference to any hardware, other than (obliquely) RAM.   A core dump is the memory profile of a particular process at a particular point in time.   If that particular point includes an access violation, it can be used to find it much like debugging in real time.

Comment: Right. I do look at the core dumps (with `ddd`) each time something like this happens. And, indeed, the backtrace always points to `malloc` or `free`. Of course it's unlikely that it's glibc that's to blame, but none of the calls that I've seen from our code or the third-party code present any obvious mistakes. It seems that something glibc is taking as a given is being violated by another part of our code (or the third-party library) that's then causing a crash when an otherwise normal memory operation takes place.

Comment: The thing about a debugger is if you've violated your own memory segmentation internally, that's not going to trigger a segfault immediately per se and so the debugger won't catch it.  What then *might* happen is the random corruption leads to a mysterious segfault down the line, and that's all you see.   The nice thing about valgrind is that it *will* catch the original violation, even if it doesn't lead to an obvious problem..

Comment: ..This means you do have to run it on an executable, not a core dump, but it also means that you probably don't have to reproduce the exact context of a crash, you just need to execute the pathway that produced the violation; if your `ERROR SUMMARY` isn't `0 from 0`, you need to track down the causes and fix them.

Comment: This site is for users and administrators, not for programmers. This question could be marginally construed as on-topic since it could be relevant to users wishing to analyze crashes in programs they didn't write. But since you wrote the code, this is primarily a programming question, which is off-topic here. And you are more likely to get good debugging advice on [so] than here. I'm voting to migrate your question; do not repost, it will be migrated automatically after a few more votes.